# Why does logger persist even when instance spawning it has been deleted?

Tags: python, oop, logging

There was a weird issue happening yesterday. I got it fixed but still don't understand why things were happening the way they did.

So I have a class with an instance of a logger getting initialised in `__init__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        
       self.logger = self._initialise_logger()
       self.logger.info(f'Initialising an instance of {self.__class__.__name__}')
       self.value = some_value


    def _initialise_logger(self):
       # Setting up logger
       return logger
```

The class is meant to perform some calculations and at one stage I had to run it in a loop:

```
my_list = []
for m in my_list:
    f = Foo(m)
    f.calculate()
```

When this loop was running I started getting strange messages in the output. On the first run the messages would be normal, but on the second run they would be duplicated, then on the next run every logging message would appear three times and so on.

So I figured that somehow the instance of the class that spawned the logger might be persisting and logger keeps printing messages so I decided that I could just manually delete the instance when calculations are completed and the issue will be gone:

```
my_list = []
for m in my_list:
    f = Foo(m)
    f.calculate()
    del f
```

That didn't work. In the end I fixed it by initialising an instance only once and then change the value of the instance variable inside the loop:

```
my_list = []
f = Foo()
for m in my_list:
    f.value = m
    f.calculate()
```

This fixed the problem but I still don't understand how a logger can persist even when the instance that spawned it has been deleted?

**EDIT:**

```
    def _initialise_logger(self):
        log_file = self._get_logging_filename()

        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + "." + self.__class__.__name__)
        logger.propagate = False
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)04d,%(name)s,%(levelname)s,%(message)s',
                                           datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        screen_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        screen_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        screen_formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)02d,%(levelname)s: -> %(message)s',
                                             datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        screen_handler.setFormatter(screen_formatter)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        logger.addHandler(screen_handler)

        logger.info(f'\n\n\n\n\nInitiating a {self.__class__.__name__} instance.')

        return logger
```

Comment: what's contained inside `_initialise_logger()`?

Comment: Just regular settings - setting up two handlers (stream and file), setting up message formats and levels for both.

Comment: Can you actually paste the code. There is only one "logger" in python. So when you create new handlers, it's adding ontop of the existing logger, not creating a new one. You typically don't want to perform logger setup logic inside a python class. It's typically done once, at the module/package level.

Comment: Updated my post with the requested code.

Comment: You cannot manually delete objects in Python. `del x` does not delete an object; it unassigns a variable. There is no problem in Python for which "delete an object" is the correct solution.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, yes, I thought as much. I knew that it was a weird solution but I decided to test to see whether it will work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of things that are wrong with your code, but for starters, let's take a look at the below example to get a better understanding of the logging module:

```py
import logging
def make_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt="%(message)s"))

    logger.addHandler(sh)
    return logger

logger_A = make_logger("A")
logger_A.warning("hi")
>>> hi

logger_B = make_logger("B")
logger_B.warning("bye")
>>> bye

logger_C1 = make_logger("C")
logger_C2 = make_logger("C")
logger_C1.warning("bonjour")
>>> bonjour
>>> bonjour
```

Notice we only get repeats when we use the same name for multiple loggers. This is because there can only be one instance of a logger with a given name, so if you call `getLogger(name)` with a `name` that already exists, it will just return the already existing logger object with that name. So, when we call our function `make_logger` twice with the same name, we're basically adding two different Stream Handlers to the same logger, which is why we see the double logging.

In your code, you construct the logger name using `__name__ + "." + self.__class__.__name__`. This produces a string that will be the exact same for every instance of your class. You could change that line of code to give a unique string for every different instance of your class, but this isn't really how you should be using the logging module.

I highly recommend reviewing [this article](https://realpython.com/python-logging/) to learn more about logging in python.

Why not just use one logger declared globally in your module/file? If you need to include identifying information for specific instance, you can always just include it in the log message itself:

```py
import logging

logger = # set up your logger here, after your imports, before your code


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, some_value):
       self.value = some_value
       logger.info(f'Initiating a {self.__class__.__name__} instance.')
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had an awful lot of experience with loggers, so no surprise there's lots wrong here. What other issues do you see?